# How to use TINYMCE 4 in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, tinymce, wysiwyg, tinymce-4

I have been trying to add an editor to a Drupal site which lets me insert images and videos and Tinymce 4 has all those features. I have installed the WYSIWYG module and am still not able to install Tinymce to it. Tried searching a little and found few patch files which am not sure will fix the issue, also I have no idea how to use patch files since I am new to Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice discussion going on here (in the comments) :
https://www.drupal.org/node/1968318

The patch seems to work for some, so it's worth a try.

Answer (score -1):

Patching is not only for drupal.
Just do not use Tinymce 4.x.
Try to install  Tinymce 3.x. This is the easiest way to make WYSIWYG and TinyMCE to be frends

Comment: Thanks :) I haven't tried the solution since using CK Editor's module did the job :)